# Duplicate GridViews are generated inside UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm working with ASP.NET 3.5 Webform.
I got an issue of duplicate unwanted rendering of GridView in an ASP.NET 3.5 Page by using UpdatePanel.

In fact, I have 3 Dropdownlists outside of an UpdatePanel (the Conditional mode). Inside the UpdatePanel, there is a GridView.
The GridView's data will be filtered automatically based on the SelectedItem change in the 3 DropdownList.

Everything works fine except a strange behavior:

- When I had created a no-result filter by using the 3 DropDownList
- Then I reselected the DropDownList to produce a filter with data, but there will be duplicate GridViews generated in the HTML page, which raises the follow client side error: 
  "Multiple controls with the same ID 'myGridView$SelectedRowPosition' were found. Trace requires that controls have unique IDs."

Did anyone use to encount such a problem and come up with an solution for that?

Thanks beforehand for your help,

Best regards,

James

Comment: Can you please share the Code.

Answer (score 0):

You could forget to close some tags. Check unclosed tags on the page.